# Как выполнить отладку зависшего процесса ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, отладка, процесс

При выполнении на удаленном сервере через ssh команды 
`iostat -dkx 2 2`
соответствующий процесс на локальной машине не завершается и остается "висеть".
Как узнать в чем причина подобного "зависания"? Можно ли выполнить отладку этого процесса?

Comment: попробуйте запустить команду в screen. В случае зависания можно будет присоединиться повторно и посмотреть процессы

Comment: На **локальной** машине или на **удаленной** процесс ведет себя некорректно? В чем проблема подключиться снова по ssh и рассмотреть, что творится с процессами?

Comment: @Ostin Спачибо, попробую.

Comment: @approximatenumber процесс подвисает на локальной машине, на удаленной машине подобных процессов нет.